# Message notification in django

Tags: django

i have simple message model in my study project.

```
  class Message(models.Model):

    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='sender')
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='reciever')
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I send notification to `request.user` about new message.
i.e. I need send notification to `request.user` if I have new Message object with `request.user` in `reciever` field

UPD my view:

```
def dialog(request, user_pk):

    sent = Message.objects.filter(reciever_id=user_pk, sender_id=request.user.pk)
    recieved = Message.objects.filter(reciever_id=request.user.pk, sender_id=user_pk)
    mate = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_pk)

    dialog_list = sorted(chain(sent, recieved), key=lambda a:a.created_at)

    if request.POST:

        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                f = form.save(commit=False)
                f.sender = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
                f.reciever = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
                form.save()
    else:
        form=MessageForm()

    return render(request, 'dialog.html', {'sent':sent, 
    'recieved':recieved, 'form':form, 'mate':mate, 'dialog_list':dialog_list})
```

look's like this:
[image]

Comment: This is a very broad question; it would be helpful if you could be more specific about what you're trying to do, or about what you've already tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: I just want advice.  I think I need flag in my `Message` model, like "viewed" and "not"  by request.user. And then check in my database for "not viewed" `Message.reciever` by `request.user`. But I don't now how I can do it

Comment: Well, an unread flag is a good idea. [BooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) is the field you want for that. Then, in the appropriate view, you can check for messages using [queryset filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

Comment: Thank you, I now about filters and BooleanField. But how I can realize logic   'view' = `True`, 'not viewed' = `False` in my view function. I update my question by this view

Comment: If you want the template to be able to understand which messages have been viewed or not then you probably want dialog_list to be a dict and not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making some ugly logic
Update my model with boolean field:

```
class Message(models.Model):

    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='sender')
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='reciever')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_readed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In view I create `set` for my message and add users here, who have messages with `is_readed == False`
It become `True` when we load dialog page with this user
I never working in real project, but I think this solution unacceptable here.
Anyway in my first study project it's worked, maybe it helped some newbies, like me*emphasized text*

```
def dialog(request, user_pk):

    sent = Message.objects.filter(reciever_id=user_pk, sender_id=request.user.pk)
    recieved = Message.objects.filter(reciever_id=request.user.pk, sender_id=user_pk)
    not_readed = set()

    for message in recieved:
        message.is_readed = True
        message.save()

    for message in Message.objects.filter(reciever_id=request.user.pk):
        if message.is_readed ==False:
            not_readed.add(CustomUser.objects.get(pk=message.sender_id))

    dialog_list = sorted(chain(sent, recieved), key=lambda a:a.created_at)

    if request.POST:

        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            f.sender = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
            f.reciever = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
            form.save()
    else:
        form=MessageForm()

    return render(request, 'dialog.html', {'sent':sent, 
    'recieved':recieved, 'form':form, 'mate':mate, 
    'dialog_list':dialog_list, 'not_readed':not_readed})
```